# Clojurescript re-frame: Changing focus to a newly-created element

Tags: clojurescript, re-frame

I am building a re-frame app with a list of text input fields. I would like the behavior to be that when the user presses `RETURN`, a new row is created and focus is placed on the new row. I have succeeded in creating the new row, however, when I attempt to change focus to that new row with this call within `change-focus` event-handler:

`(.focus (.getElementById js/document focus-element))`

I am getting an error: `Cannot read property 'focus' of null`.

I presume that is because the view has not yet rendered the newly created row. What is the best way to go about changing focus to a new element using re-frame?

Should I put the active-row in my *state atom* and render that in the view? Or possibly fire another event after the view has been rendered? I'd love some input.

Answer (score 0):

If each row that your form adds is component, then you can set handler on `componentDidMount` lifecycle callback. It will be called after component already rendered. To do that in `re-frame` you should use `reagent`'s `create-class` like that

```
(defn my-row [input-id]
  (reagent/create-class
   {:component-did-mount
    #(.focus (.getElementById js/document input-id))
    :reagent-render
    (fn [input-id]
      [:div.form-group
       [:input.form-control {:id input-id, :type "text"}]])}))
```

You can try to play with React.JS refs or `reagent/dom-node` instead of using JS interop code in `componentDidMount` handler function.